# Filter date range in Dataframe

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I am very much new to the scala and I have dataframe with Id and valid_From and Valid_to Date as below :

```
DataFrame1 (`name in query as tD`): 
id  E_id    start_date  CTC     valid_from  valid_to
z1  it1     2016-01-01  25      2016-02-01  2017-03-01 
z1  it1     2017-01-01  25.75   2017-03-01  null
```

And I have another Dataframe as below :

DataFrame 2 (`name in query as finalDF`):

```
id  D_id   Join_date
z1  it1    2016-05-01
z1  it1    2017-06-01
```

and I am joining these two dataframes on the basis of `id` and `D_id` and need records where DataFrame 2 Join_Date lies between DataFrame 1 start_date and valid_to.So the final output should be like

```
id  D_id
z1  it1 
z1  it1
```

I am doing this like :

```
val  joinDF = finalDF.as("DF")
   .join(tD.as("tDF"),($"tDF.id" === $"DF.id" && $"tDF.D_id" === $"DF.D_id"))
   .filter($"Join_date".between($"start_date", $"valid_to") || $"Join_date".between($"start_date", $"valid_to".isNull))
```

But this is not working .Please help me.

Comment: It's not working how exactly? Not giving any results? Giving the wrong result? Please, elaborate.

Comment: it is not working after OR condition which is including || $"Join_date".between($"start_date", $"valid_to".isNull).

How can i mention to include the record where join_Date lies between start_date to valid_to where valid_to is null

Comment: can you please suggest me the filter condition after OR .What I am doing wrong

Comment: How about `|| ($"valid_to".isNull && $"Join_date" >= $"start_date")`?